# Intranet Design and Development Book Recommendations

Tags: books, recommendations, intranet

Can anyone recommend any good books on Intranet planning and implementation for the business professional / manager?

Thanks

Russell

Comment: I've just had Jakob Nielsons 10 Best Intranets review recommended to me.

http://www.useit.com/alertbox/intranet_design.html

It's a good read but the overiview doesn't go in to the depth I'd like and $224 for the full report is a bit more than I'm looking to pay for personal reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just picked up a copy of SharePoint Design by WROX.   So far I am quite impressed.  It is ideal for users that need to get up to speed with design principles and different best practices for intranet and publishing portal developmentwith MOSS.  It also covers general design principles and has many references.

Comment: I think this is about as close as I'm going to get for a recent book.  Looks like the perfect level of technical depth I am looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Intranet blog at http://www.intranetblog.com/ they have lots of good articles and reviews that should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For business professionals and specifically for SharePoint theres no getting around reading the 1200+ pages in  [Planning and architecture for Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262757.aspx)