# An introduction to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, administration, learning

I've been a member of Stack Overflow for a while and have this week been given a project of having a play around with SharePoint 2010 to see how it works basically, as we're looking to use it to replace our existing intranet site sometime soon.

We have a consultant coming in to help us in the next few months but really at the moment I'm starting from a base of knowing almost nothing about SharePoint, so I've been told to get up to speed. I've looked into it over the past two weeks and what tasks it can do etc, but now I'm actually having a play with it and seeing how you administer `SharePoint 2010` and perform tasks within it.

So what I'm looking for here are any materials that people have found useful when learning about SharePoint. I'm not looking for development materials as yet (I come from a C# programming background), but just administration stuff, like how to pull AD usergroups into SharePoint groups, creating sites where users can enter their own newsfeeds and any handy tips or tricks.

*edit* Other introductions are also welcome such as development and designing.

Comment: Hi manemawanna, welcome to our community! This type of question that has several answers should be marked as community wiki. Read why here http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean

Comment: @Anders Rask, could you correct yr link, the site http://www.sharepointoverflow.com does not exist

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This question has come up before. Take a look in the Related column on the right where you will find 4-6 similar questions:

- [Getting started with SharePoint 2010
  for SharePoint 2007 Developers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/468/getting-started-with-sharepoint-2010-for-sharepoint-2007-developers)
- [Recommendations for SharePoint 2010
  training?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/recommendations-for-sharepoint-2010-training)
- [What resources would you recommend
  to someone who would like to learn
  and possibly become a SharePoint
  Developer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-resources-would-you-recommend-to-someone-who-would-like-to-learn-and-possibl)
- [What technical skills do you use
  most when developing/deploying
  SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3191/what-technical-skills-do-you-use-most-when-developing-deploying-sharepoint)
- [Intranet Design and Development Book
  Recommendations](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302/intranet-design-and-development-book-recommendations)

Comment: Thank you very much I did have a search but couldn't find anything initially.

Answer (score 22):

**Free for all:**

- IT Pro:
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518660
- Developer:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147

**For MS Partner:**

- IT Pro: [Ignite Training](https://training.partner.microsoft.com/learning/app/management/registrationex/LMS_Registration.aspx?UserMode=0&Mode=0&ActivityID=577057)
- Developer: [Ignite Training](https://training.partner.microsoft.com/learning/app/management/registrationex/LMS_Registration.aspx?UserMode=0&Mode=0&ActivityID=577062)

Answer (score 17):

The **Lynda SharePoint Essentials Training** is an excellent starter video series for understanding the general components and concepts behind SharePoint.

**[Getting Started Developing on SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147)** from MSDN is an authoritative guide for fresh developers.

For an understanding more towards the business side of things, start with the Total Economic Impact of SharePoint at http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730143

For workflows, when you are confident of your basic knowledge, you will want to check out the official **SP 2010 Workflows Overview** at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff819861

Answer (score 11):

You can purchase a book on the subject or spend some time reading blogs.  There are many good ones out there that can help you either better understand the features and components of SharePoint or to tackle specific issues or implementations.

Since you are looking at this for an Intranet replacement, I would highly recommend you focus on some Information Architecture/Design and Taxonomy topics since this can be a critical component.

Answer (score 8):

Get Started Developing on SharePoint 2010
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147.aspx

Answer (score 8):

My favourite site for SharePoint training is [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com) which provides videos for both developer, administrator and end-user. Sorted in categories for beginner, intermediate and advanced users.

Answer (score 7):

All SharePoint people  visit this site Microsoft official ESP
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/Pages/esp_archive.aspx   number of videos of all Features of sharepoint

Answer (score 6):

You can go through the links mentioned below to have much confidence in learning, customizing and administration SharePoint 2010:

1. http://blogs.technet.com/b/dennisgo/archive/2011/08/29/sharepoint-2010-learning-resources-and-other-good-stuff.aspx
2. http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/

I hope these links will help you to have some grip over the world around SharePoint 2010...