# Sharepoint Learning

Tags: learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An introduction to SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/an-introduction-to-sharepoint-2010)

i want some knowledge base tutorials (help) to learn share point 2010 (or foundation) configuration and development. 
i used to work on windows share point services. 
Give me some ideas where to start from.
Need suggestions :)

Thanks

Saad Tahir