# Getting Started with SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An introduction to SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/an-introduction-to-sharepoint-2010)

i have experience of SharePoint 2007 and WSS 3.0, then i switch to the windows form platform. Now again i m interested to start with SharePoint 2010/Foundation.

Does anyone know the good resource to start with or to start from ?

Thanks