# Sharepoint 2010 Learning

Tags: tutorials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An introduction to SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/an-introduction-to-sharepoint-2010)

All,

I have been asked to learn Sharepoint 2010 and develop a workflow. My problem is that I am totally new to Sharepoint 2010. I been developing apps in C#, Java etc., but have not developed even 1 single SP apps.

I have heard from people saying that it is going to be steep learning curve. Can someone guide me how to learn SP 2010 to understand concepts.

Thanks.